# How to retain blockdev changes after server restart?

Tags: ubuntu, block-device

I am setting block device read ahead buffer size like so:

```
blockdev --setra 8192 /dev/sda
```

As suggested [here](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/291-blockdev-command-examples). 
The problem is after restart it goes back to 256 (default). **I need it to retain the value i set it to**. How can i do this? 
I'm on **Ubuntu 16.04 x64**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to arrange to have the command run at boot time.

In the past, you could do this by placing it in the file `/etc/rc.local`. You can still do this, if you wish. Just create the file (as it does not exist by default anymore) and it will be run on next boot.

---

You can also simply create a new systemd oneshot unit which runs your desired command at boot time. For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set readahead for the hard drive device
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/blockdev --setra 8192 /dev/sda

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You might use this latter method if you expect admins of this server to not be familiar with the old rc.local script.